# Regex returning only portion of a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex string:

```
(@Model.[a-z]*)
```

I'm trying to use it to pull certain values from a razor view email.
So we could have the following values:

- @Model.FirstName
- @Model.Company

I would expect the following code to return these values in a list:

```
Regex.Matches(emailString, "@Model.[a-z]*").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value)
```

Instead I just get a list of the same value "@Model."
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values can contain both lowercase and uppercase, therefore the regexp should be:

```
(@Model\.[a-zA-Z]*)
```

... or you can put `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option but that would apply also to `Model` part.

Comment: Well, the unescaped dot matches any char other than a newline. `@Model.[a-zA-Z]*` will match `@Model~`.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a *case insensitive* approach:

```
Regex.Matches(emailString, "@Model.[a-z]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using Razor.

Then Consider not Placing the @Model inside of the Quotation marks

EG

```
Regex.Matches(emailString, "@Model.[a-z]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

instead use it like this

```
Regex.Matches(emailString, Model + ".[a-z]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```